# R6010 abort when getting non existing element from vector, mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I have `vector<pair<wstring, double>>` vector, and when I try to get wstring from some non existing element and to put it to static text field in dialog, this R6010 error appears.

But I don't know how to check if element exists.

I tried this and it didn't work.

```
if(thatVector.at(0).first.c_str() != NULL)
    staticText.SetWindowText(thatVector.at(0).first.c_str());
```

Comment: You may check whether element's index is in range of vector's indexes like
`if (i <= thatVector.size()) ...`

Comment: Good enough, thanks.